# How do I align this search box to the right?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm just starting to get the hang of HTML. I can't manage to align this to the right, it's part of a menu. I basically want it to align the search box to the right so it looks like facebook or something like that. Till now I've been using padding but I cannot keep it going any longer.

```
<li id="search-10" class="widget_search">
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Ir a Ciudad"/>
    </div>
    </form></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `float:right` or `right:0;` to your `.widget_search` css class

Comment: My question MIGHT help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117707/how-to-align-one-form-element-within-a-li-with-the-other-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options:

```
keep the div(bad way)
add align"right" to the div
on the form and remove the div (better way)
use float:right
text-align: right
```

And place that on the form and remove the div.

Also I recommend putting styling in a css and not in the html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:right;` to your `form` and remove the unnecessary `div`.

Note that this will only work for inline elements: text, inputs, anchors, etc. If you want boxes (divs, forms, tables, etc.) to align to the right you need to use `float:right;` and set a height on the parent of the floated item, or add a clear div bellow the floated item. Also, besides being unnecessary, this second approach would be more complicated to use for you, as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't use a list

```
<div id="search-10" class="widget_search">
  <form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div style="text-align: right;">
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Ir a Ciudad"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I would also suggest you experiment with `text-align`

Comment: He probably has multiple items in that list. How are you so sure his choice isn't justified?

Comment: @Alin +1 for being objective! You are right the `li` might be justified, though that is part of a larger discussion. I _personally_ find `li`'s to be over used when the items have no relationship to each other.