# How to align one "form" element within a "li", with the other "li"?

Tags: html, css

I've created  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jammim19/sPx34/22/) to illustrate my error.

I simply want to align all the "li" elements within the "ul"

```
<div id="easySearchMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Categories
            <ul>
                <li>Classifieds</li>
                <li>Business listings</li>
                <li>Propetries</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Advanced Search</li>
        <li>
            <form id="searchForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter your search" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" value="" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>Log in / Register</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try playing with the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) CSS property on your `li`s.

Comment: I altered "display" to "inline-block"                                 I almost have it perfect: jsfiddle.net/jammim19/sPx34/26

Answer (score 0):

change your code like below

```
<div id="easySearchMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Categories
            <ul>
                <li>Classifieds</li>
                <li>Business listings</li>
                <li>Propetries</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Advanced Search</li>
        <li style="padding: 8px 20px 7px 20px;">
            <form>
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter your search">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" value="">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>Log in / Register</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

finaly change your css, from selector `div.input` remove the `float:right;` property/value pair.

Comment: Sorry that just removes the "form" form the li entirely.  What could you recommend for the width.

Comment: In my previous answer, search form moved under advanced search menu. Now search field is inline item at your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You're using block level elements in your inner ul, causing unnecessary complications.

You could change your `fieldset` to `display:inline-block` to align those boxes, although that doesn't help with the different heights.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I almost have it perfect:  http://jsfiddle.net/jammim19/sPx34/26/